# Problems compiling with openmpi after upgrade to v 1.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, compiling, fortran, mpi

I have been using openmpi to develop fortran90 parallel applications for a while. I usually install the default version of openmpi for developers from the repositories and it works out of the box. I did so and it worked when I firstly installed Ubuntu16.04 on my local machine.

However I think openmpi has been upgraded and my programs won't compile anymore. I tried on other machines which use older versions (libopenmpi-dev 1.6) and it works. It seems the compiler does not recognise basic subroutines such as MPI_RECV(..).

For example this little piece of code fails to compile in my local machine, but it has no problem on another one with openmpi1.6.

```
program main
   use mpi
   implicit none
   integer :: ierr,np,myid,i,rbuf
   integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: ista

   CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)

   CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid,ierr) 

   CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,np,ierr) 


   allocate(ista(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,np))


   if (myid==0) then
         do i = 1, np-1
            CALL MPI_RECV(rbuf,1,MPI_INTEGER4,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ista,ierr)
            write(*,"('process ',i2,' sent:',i2)") i,rbuf
         end do
   else
         i=10*myid
         CALL MPI_SEND(i,1,MPI_INTEGER4,0,myid,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   end if

   CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)


end program main
```

Compiling this using mpif90 gives me the following error:

```
 main.f90:19:75:

             CALL MPI_RECV(rbuf,1,MPI_INTEGER4,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ista,ierr)
                                                                           1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at (1)
```

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thank you very much in advance